# AVCaptureSession failed after another AVAudioSession is configured

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, ios8, avfoundation

I try to implement both audio recording and video recording features. For audio, use *AVAudioRecorder*, for video, use AVFoundation (AVCaptureSession+AVAssetWriter).

Here's my audio setup

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:&error];
[session setActive:YES error:&error];

NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC]  forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMedium]  forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0]             forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]                     forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:&error];
self.recorder.delegate = self;
self.recorder.meteringEnabled = NO;
[self.recorder prepareToRecord];
```

Here's my catpure session setup

```
NSError *error = nil;
_captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
_captureSession.usesApplicationAudioSession = NO;

_captureDeviceAudio = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
_captureDeviceInputAudio = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_captureDeviceAudio error:&error];

// capture device ouputs
_captureOutputAudio = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];
_captureOutputVideo = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

[_captureOutputAudio setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_captureCaptureDispatchQueue];
[_captureOutputVideo setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_captureCaptureDispatchQueue];

// Skip code here add AVCaptureDeviceInput and audio/video input/output
```

Here's the issues comes by doing the following.

1. Create & init AVCaptureSession, everything works fine
2. Create & init the audio recording, everything works fine
3. Reuse the existing AVCaptureSession, the delegate method *captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:* won't receive any audio data
4. Recreate & init AVCaptureSession, fix it (but this is not performant solution)

This is very strange to me. By setting usesAppicationAudioSession = NO, the capture session will maintain a private audio session with settings that separated from the shared audioSession. If that's the case, anything i change on the shared AudioSession (in my audio setup) **shouldn't** affect

Comment: A lot of people are having this issue. There are some glimmers of hope, such as references to using https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio